# Installing issue DSharp and Spring4D

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, spring4d

I am try to install DSharp from repository in Delphi XE6.
I am use

- Spring4D + release/1.2 (2016-09-02)
- DSharp + feature/spring4d-1.2 (2016-07-05)
- Delphi XE6

Build Spring4D is now OK.

In packages project DSharp for Delphi XE6 missings sources `DSharp.Core.EventArgs.pas` and `DSharp.Core.Events.pas`.

I removed this from project.

Build All packages DSharp is OK.
But when I can install dcl... from DSharp I got this errors:

First Error:

[image]

Second error after first:

[image]

Components for DSharp not installed of course.

DSharp still incompatible with Spring4D 1.2?

Comment: Why would you want to install packages? Isn't this a non visual library. Add the source to your project or use a search path.

Comment: DSharp includes some visual components.

Comment: You have some old dcu, bpl or dcp files lying around. `Spring.TFieldTable` does not exist (it was renamed to `TInitTable` some while ago). Make sure you delete them first and do a clean build/install.